# How do I manipulate character case in search and replace in vim?

Tags: vim, replace

for example, I have:

```
  double foo = 0.0;  
  double bar = 0.0;
```

and I want to write some sort of search to find each variable and change it to:

```
  double Foo = 0.0;  
  double Bar = 0.0;
```

I dont want to do these one variable at a time (e.g. :%s/foo/Foo/g) but rather all at once, something close to

```
:%s/  double \(\w\+\)/  double \1/c
```

(and somehow capitialize the first character of \1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `\u` prefix for the match in the replace clause:

For one at a time:

```
:%s/ double \(\w\+\)/ double \u\1/c
```

For all at once:

```
:%s/ double \(\w\+\)/ double \u\1/g
```

If you want to make the whole match uppercase use the `\U` and `\E` delimiters:

```
:%s/ double \(\w\+\)/ double \U\1\E/g
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know of a good place to look at all these commands?  And how would I change the whole string to uppercase? and what is the command for lowercase?

Comment: `:help substitute` and more specifically `:help sub-replace-special`

Comment: You can just use `\l` instead of `\u` to do lowercase, and `\L`/`\E` for multiple characters

Answer (score 1):

Use \u

```
%s/ double \(\w\+\)/ double \u\1/c
```

Comment: Would not find "double" at the begining of the line, else it's ok.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't get the other's to work, this works for me:

```
:%s/\(double \)\<\(\w\)\(\w*\)\>/\1\u\2\L\3/g
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s:\(\<double\>\)\(\<\w\+\>\):\1 \u\2:g
```

or sume-such.