# Vim search and replace variable names with uppercase

Tags: search, vim, replace, refactoring

I have a file with a few hundred lines of code. I'd like to search through the file and change all of a variable name to uppercase. Imagine like this:

```
:%s/variable_name/<gUaw>/g
```

...would change `variable_name` to `VARIABLE_NAME`

Is there a more 'vim' way to do this than just running the search/replace for each variable, typing both the original name and the uppercase name?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I manipulate character case in search and replace in vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10745694/how-do-i-manipulate-character-case-in-search-and-replace-in-vim)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvim%5D+replace+uppercase

Comment: In your case it's simpply `:%s/variable_name/\U&/g`

Comment: Thanks @phd, that's exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@phd got it: `:%s/variable_name/\U&/g`. Thanks for the assist!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a macro for that:

First, search for your pattern:

```
/yourPattern
```

Then count the number of occurrences:

```
:%s///n
```

Finally, create your macro:

```
qqngUawq
```

`qq` starts recording the macro in the register `q`, `n` goes no the next occurence`and the final`q` stops the recording.

Execute it n-1th times (the nth time was done by creating the macro):

```
42@q
```

Here n-1 == 42 ;-) replace 42 by your number of occurences.